# android: starting activity from listview didnt work

Tags: android, listview

i make my code more simple its still didnt work for me when i click on item on list view it do nothing

```
 public class MainActivity extends Activity {

String[] elements = {"item1", "item2"};

public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
     super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

      setContentView(R.layout.list); 
     ListView listview = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.listView1);
     listview.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, elements));
 }

public void onListItemClick(ListView parent, View v, int position, long id) {

    if ("item1".equals(elements[position]))
        {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "item1",
                   Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        Intent myIntent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, myactivity.class);
        startActivity(myIntent);
        }
    else if ("item2".equals(elements[position]))
        {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "item2",
                   Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        Intent myIntent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, myactivity.class);
        startActivity(myIntent);
        }

    }
}
```

May I know what is the correct way to achieve my objective?

Comment: Use an onitemclicklistener. Really don't know what you mean with "transfer me to different xml file"

Comment: did you mean by `transform me to different xml`, opening new activity

Comment: each item open another activity have text view for example

Answer (score 0):

You have to call this after setAdapter('');

```
mainListView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener{

OnClick(item){

     // You have to call Intent(main,second) or call another fragment directly.

}
}
```

Comment: i hope you can understand what i need , when i click on item of list view show other activity have text view

Answer (score -1):

First tell me that are asking such functioning "when user click on any row then he will redirect to new activity"?

Is yes then you can use below line of codes:

```
yourlistviewobject.setOnItemClickListener(new onItemClickListener(){

@Override
protected void onListItemClick(){

     //Do stuff
    Intent intent=new Intent(this,otherclass);
   startActivity(intent);
}
});
```

Hope it will help you.

Comment: add this as comment below the question. do not post as ans if you are querying .

Comment: redirect to xml file that have text view for example

Comment: each item redirect for for xml file have text view activity